# How do I install Ubuntu to a new disk on a system that already has a disk with Windows installed on it with BitLocker enabled?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows, luks

I'm creating this question because I wasn't able to find existing questions after searching that described the issue I ran into. Existing questions dealt with the scenario where you want to install Ubuntu alongside an existing Windows installation with BitLocker enabled. My scenario is that I've added a new, separate disk to my system and I want to install Ubuntu onto that.

I'm also going to answer the question myself with a workaround that I ended up using. Depending on what the community thinks when they encounter this question, a bug report may end up being created if this scenario isn't supposed to require a workaround.

Here's what my setup was before installing the new disk:

- SSD 1 - Windows 11 (with BitLocker)
- SSD 2 - Ubuntu 22.04 (with LUKS)

Here's what it looked like after I added the new disk and began trying to install Ubuntu (onto SSD 3):

- SSD 1 - Windows 11 (with BitLocker)
- SSD 2 - Ubuntu 22.04 (with LUKS)
- SSD 3 - unformatted

Here's what my ultimate goal was for my three disk:

- SSD 1 - Windows 11 (with BitLocker)
- SSD 2 - Ubuntu 22.04 (with LUKS)
- SSD 3 - Ubuntu 23.10 (with LUKS)

I downloaded the latest version of Ubuntu for desktop computers, made a USB with it, and booted from the USB to install it. I did not uninstall or otherwise modify either of my two existing operating systems on SSD 1 and SSD 2. This is the same pattern I've used before when I want to install a Linux distribution to my system which already has operating systems installed.

This workflow has worked fine for me in the past. I would select that I want to erase a disk and install Ubuntu onto it, and then I'd be prompted to select which disk I want to use. I would choose the new, unformatted disk, and the installation process would create partitions for me and install Ubuntu onto that disk.

But this time, this workflow didn't work for me. I began the installation process, but when it got to the part where I select that I want to erase a disk and install Ubuntu onto it, it showed me that because BitLocker was detected, installation would not be able to continue. It did not get to the step where I select which disk I intend to use. If it did get that far, I would have chosen the new, unformatted disk I had just installed into my system.

Here is what I saw...

First, I select that I want to erase and use an entire disk, and include LUKS encryption (I tried this with and without LUKS, it made no difference).

[image: a wizard screen]

Then, it shows me that BitLocker is detected. I cannot continue.

[image: a wizard screen]

I found that if I chose the manual partitioning option, it did detect that I had an unused disk.

[image: a wizard screen]

However, I do not know much about manual partitioning and I did not understand how to complete the steps on that screen to set up my new disk for installing Ubuntu onto it. I wanted to rely on the installation wizard setting up my partitions for me like I always have before.

It seems like the installation process is detecting that *some* disk, not necessarily the one I intend to install Ubuntu onto, has a Windows installation with BitLocker enabled on it. And at that point, the installation process decides that installation of Ubuntu cannot continue.

I think that this behavior shows that a bug exists in the installation process because, to the best of my knowledge, BitLocker being present on my system on one of the other disks than the one I want to install Ubuntu onto should not prevent installing Ubuntu. In the past, this has never been an issue for me, though I admit that I might be remembering how I did my Windows + Ubuntu multiple disk setup before incorrectly, and perhaps this is how it's always worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the workaround that I used which resulted in me being able to install all three operating systems with full disk encryption enabled.

I suspected that if I disabled BitLocker, I would be able to proceed past that step in the installation wizard. Then, I would be able to select the new disk, install Ubuntu onto it, and then re-enable BitLocker in my Windows installation.

After disabling BitLocker in Windows and waiting for it to finish decrypting data, I tried the Ubuntu installation again.

This time, I was not presented with the BitLocker warning screen.

Here is what I saw...

I chose the "erase disk and use it" option as described in the original question, and then I saw this.

[image: a wizard screen]

So this time, it allows installation to continue, and I can select any of the detected disks. One of the detected disks is the new empty disk (`sda` in the screenshot).

[image: a wizard screen]

I select that disk and I am able to proceed to the part of the installation wizard that I originally expected to get to. It tells me which partitions it will set up on the new disk.

[image: a wizard screen]

I am happy with them and I proceed. Ubuntu installs.

After ensuring Ubuntu was installed correctly, I boot back into Windows and re-enable BitLocker. After it finishes encrypting data, I ensure that I can boot into each of my three operating systems. I can, and I consider the workaround successful.

If the behavior I experienced is not desired, where the installation process was blocked by the presence of BitLocker on a disk unrelated to the disk I intended to install Ubuntu onto, then a bug report should be opened. If anyone can let me know how to get started with filing such a bug report (e.g. comment on this answer), I'm happy to get that started.

Comment: Bugs can be reported to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity . Though the bug and workaround are both valid, I would have simply unplugged the problematic disk.

Comment: Thanks for the link. To be clear, when you say "problematic" disk, you're talking about the one with Windows already installed on it, right? I didn't think to do that because I thought it was important that all the disks I planned to use in my final setup be present and detected while I installed Ubuntu to one of them. Now that I think about it, that's only needed if I want GRUB to be aware of all three operating systems, and I'd make sure they're all plugged in once I get to the step where I update GRUB from one of the Ubuntu installations.